# UIButton border disappears

Tags: ios, uikit, interface-builder

I'm designing a new button for an app, I'd like to avoid coding as I have to use the same button style through the app. I added some attributes and it works fine, but when I add a border color (doesn't matter which color) for no reason the border disappears. What is going on?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not set some properties of a view's layer through interface builder. You can set a layer's `borderWidth` and `cornerRadius` via `Interface Builder` tool of `Xcode`, but you will not be able to set borderColor using `Interface Builder` and it's probably because the `layer.borderColor` wants a `CGColor` instead of a `UIColor`. And unfortunately, there's no way to assign a `CGColorRef` type in `Interface Builder`.

You can programmatically set the button's border color on its layer as-

```
[[button layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
```

Comment: So, why do they accept color as a type on Interface Builder?

Comment: It's for setting those properties which accepts UIColor

Answer (score 1):

`layer.borderColor` requires a `CGColorRef` but the color set using the Interface Builder is of `UIColor` type. That is the reason `borderColor` is not showing on your button.

You'll have to set it programmatically.